# Securing Webmethods

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am using JQuery AJAX with webmethods . As regular session authentication wont work in webmethod what are possible methods of securing webmethods so that a user wont copy that url from client debugging tools and use it .

Comment: Authentication and authorization doesn't work for web methods?  Are you sure?  What mechanism have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: In addition to authentication and authorization which "do" work as David mentioned, you should minify your javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sessions in your webmethods. Simply add (true) into your WebMethod attribute.

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public string MyMethod
```

If you're using some of the built in authentication you can also use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")]
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `EnableSession` part of your attribute, like this: `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]`.

Comment: Why is [Authorize] not available in my code? Am I missing a "using" statement?

Comment: You most likely are missing a using statement. When you come across problems like this, in VS2013 (12 too I think), you can right click on it and you may have "Resolve >" option and it will automatically show you the correct library. Alternatively, you can go to View > ObjectBrowser and search for it. It should either be System.Web.Mvc or System.Web.Http, but it's useful to know how to track these things down.

Answer (score 1):

If your WebMethod doesn't live on the same box as the rest of your app, you can also pass in some kind of salted and hashed timestamp or other information as one of the parameters in the call.

Logic inside the webmethod itself could then decode the hash and match it to a list of currently logged in users and IPs and/or read an expiration date so the url would be useless if copied and called elsewhere.

If the WebMethods are all part of the same application though, just depending on the Session is going to be your best bet.